# How to treat variables in an expression as real?

Tags: complex, polynomials

Let's say we'd like to define a general complex polynomial and then separate the real terms from the imaginary terms. We could define

```
p[n_Integer,x_Real,y_Real]:=Sum[
  Subscript[a,k](x+I y)^k,
  {k,0,n}
]
```

so that, for example, a degree 2 polynomial has the form

```
p[2,x,y]//Expand
```

which gives

```
Subscript[a, 0]+x Subscript[a, 1]+I y Subscript[a, 1]+x^2 Subscript[a, 2]+2 I x y Subscript[a, 2]-y^2 Subscript[a, 2]
```

So far, so good.

However, let's say we'd like to only keep the terms containing an `I`. I naively tried

```
Im[p[2,x,y]//Expand]
```

but Mathematica treats the coefficients (and possibly x and y) as potentially complex, and gives the result in terms of their real and imaginary components.

I tried to include explicit assumptions, such as

```
Simplify[
  Im[p[2,x,y]//Expand],
  Assumptions->{
    Element[
      List[
        Subscript[a,k],
        {k,0,2}
      ],Reals
    ],
    Element[{x,y},Reals]
  }
]
```

but that didn't seem to make a difference.

How can I get Mathematica to treat all variables in an expression as real-valued so that the imaginary component of the expression can be simply obtained from the terms containing `I`?

Comment: you can try `p[2,x,y]//ReIm//ComplexExpand`

Comment: Your `List[a[k], {k, 0, 2}]` should be `Table[a[k], {k, 0, 2}]`. Note that `List` does not take an iterator.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for that — using `Table` solved the problem, as did the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function, which is in my opinion one of the most badly named functions in Mathematica, [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html). It expands `expr` assuming that all variables are real.

```
Clear[p, a, k];

p[n_, x_, y_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k] (x + I y)^k, {k, 0, n}]

ComplexExpand[Im[p[2, x, y]]]

(* y Subscript[a, 1] + 2 x y Subscript[a, 2] *)
```

Comment: One could also include the option [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) which can take the `{Re,Im}` argument.  Then `ComplexExpand[expr, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]` tries to yield an expression of the form `(*real part*) + I (*imaginary part*)`.